# How to schedule a task,remote access and re-run of an executable

Tags: windows

He is my dilemma, I hope someone out there has done this…
Any views or Ideas are welcome. I am new to this are so be gentle..

I have PC A that needs to have a programX (.exe) running on a regular basis every 2 Mins this checks for another file and process the file if present.

On PC B I need to be able to stop and start the program as and when on PC A remotely.
Also programX is not allowed to re-run/recheck the existence of the file until the old programX has finished.

Both PCs are running Windows 7. (This will also be used on a couple of XP machines.)

**Question 1**

How do I get the .exe to run every 2 Mins? (Task scheduler only does once daily and I don’t want to have 576 tasks)

**Question 1.1**

How do I get the .exe to start and stop remotely?

**Question 1.2**

How do I get the system to recognise that programX is already running and not finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**
I think you'd better write a service (always active) that runs a method programmatically using (for example) a timer.
**Question 1.1:**
If app on PC A exposes a class via remoting, from PC B you can run a Start() and Stop() method directly on PC A.
Using remoting you can create a main app (called server) which exposes a class (usually using interfaces) that can be accessed remotely via TCP/UDP/Pipes from localhost or internet.
Take a look at [this example](http://generally.wordpress.com/2007/05/31/a-simple-remoting-example-in-c/): this is only the first I've found searching *"C# remoting example"* in Google, but you can find hundreds.
For your need, service on PC A (see question 1) could expose via remoting a class that can start/stop the other application you run on PC A.

**Question 1.2:**
On PC A you could use a mutex (for example)

Comment: Happy with 1 and 1.2 mutex sounds great for what I need. But 1.1 what do you mean by "exposes a class" or any link please.

Comment: @icecurtain: take a look at my edited post for question 1.1. I hope it's more clear now; if not tell me.

Comment: @icecurtain: I'm assuming you're developing in C#, arent'you?